# Add items to list of class while iterating through some foreach loop

Tags: c#, list

I am declaring list of class, then looping some variables through foreach and there I want to add items to my list class.

```
List<someClass> ItemsList= new List<someClass>();
getting some other list variables.
foreach (other list) {
And here I want ItemsList.Add('adding 4 variables aas declared in someClass');
}
```

I get error `No overload for method 'Add' takes 4 arguments.`

Strange thing is I declared 4 arguments and am adding 4 items. So I don't understand why I get this error ?

Comment: Please show us a real code fragment.

Comment: `AddRange(new [] {someClassInst.Prop1, someClassInst.Prop2 .....})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't load the 4 variables *directly* into `ItemsList.Add`.  Instead, you have to declare a `new someClass` and pass your 4 variables to that instance.

For example:

```
ItemsList.Add(new someClass() { var1 = "var1value", var2 = "someothervalue", var3 = 9999, var4 = "whatever" });
```

Comment: Thanks Tam , works perfect. will accept this answer in a few minutes!